# activerecord setting in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scopes

I have a table `business_settings` that uses `key` and `value` columns to store the settings for a business.

I have written a helper to gather these values:

```
def bus_setting(bus_key)
    bus_setting = BusinessSetting.where(key: bus_key).first
    return bus_setting.nil? ? bus_key : bus_setting.value   
end
```

in this scenario the value returned is an integer with the value 90.

This is the scope i'm attempting to write, however the helper `bus_setting` causes "undefined method `bus_setting' for Class:0x00..."

```
scope :due, -> { where("mass_verification_date < ?", bus_setting('MASS_VERIFICATION_INTERVAL')to_i.days.ago) }
```

Am I going about this the write way or have I made a stupid mistake? Thanks

EDIT: This scope achieves the outcome I'm after, but I don't want to hard code the value.
`scope :due, ->  { where("mass_verification_date < ?", 90.days.ago) }`

Comment: try adding `helper_method :bus_settings` below your helper method and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ajay, thanks for your input - I've actually implemented a hybrid solution:

`mass_verification.rb`

`scope  :due, ->(n) { where("mass_verification_date < ?", n.to_i.days.ago) }`

```
def mass_interval
    mass_interval = bus_setting("MASS_VERIFICATION_INTERVAL")
end
```

and to get the `bus_setting` helper to fire:

`include BusinessSettingsHelper`

With the call looking like this:
`MassVerification.due(mass_interval)`

Thankyou again.

Answer (score 1):

```
static scope:
  scope :due, -> { where("mass_verification_date < ?", 90.days.ago) }
```

In your case, this 90.days.ago is kind of static. If you want to make it dynamic then you are supposed to use arguments for this scope.

In below example, scope :due, ->(n), here n is the argument which will be used while evaluation of the where condition.

```
Make it dynamic: 
  scope  :due, ->(n) { where("mass_verification_date < ?", n.days.ago) }
```

Now, on calling this particular scope with argument value: 3 will fetch all the business settings having mass_verfication_date < 3.days.ago

```
Call this : 
  BusinessSetting.due(3)
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation to the code you provided? Without it people may not find it very useful.